# How to use Exception control in Cordys BOP4 CU 18?

Tags: business-process-management, cordys-opentext

I am using Cordys BOP4 Technology For Application Development. So I Want to use Exception Control which is provide by Cordys IDE, but I am not able to use that properly.

So some one who know's, please tell me how to set Activity in Exception Control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the catch-exception event. Drag and drop this event on to the activity where you want to handle exceptions. 
Catch exception can be linked to any web-service, sub-process or any group (like for each, while or any embedded process). In the properties of the catch event, there is an option to choose an error code which can be either a custom error, or a generic one.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but i added Exception control on the INSERT web service but there is no option for link to that web service , there is only a check box for check or uncheck its configuration. so plz give some explaination plz...